# Ajax call to controller function not returning data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 webpage where I need to call a function on my Controller page, from my view using Ajax. My problem is, that even though the Ajax call to the function works (the function is called, and returns the data I expect), I can't get hold of the returned value in Ajax.Success, but when I make the call fail, I can get the returned value in "error".

This is my Ajax call in the View:

```
function FindFreeCards() {
$.ajax({
  url: '@Url.Action("FindFreeCards", "AdminCards")',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  type: 'POST',
  success: function (data) {
    alert('SUCCESS');
    var FreeCards;
    FreeCards = data.d;

    alert(FreeCards);

    $('#lblFreeCards').html(FreeCards);
    $('#modalSelectFreeCard').modal();
  },
  error: function (request, status, error) {
    alert('ERROR');
    alert(request.responseText);
    alert(status.toString());
    alert(error.toString());
  }
});
```

};

And this is my function in the Controller:

```
public string FindFreeCards()
{
  string FreeCards = "";

  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gbizz"].ConnectionString))
  {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCom;
    SqlDataReader sqlReader;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gbizz"].ConnectionString);
    Con.Open();
    sqlCom = new SqlCommand("LicensePlateFindFreeCard", con);
    sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 12;

    sqlReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();

    if (sqlReader.HasRows)
    {
      while (sqlReader.Read())
      {
        FreeCards = FreeCards + sqlReader["CardNo"].ToString() + ", ";
      }
    }

    FreeCards = FreeCards.Trim().TrimEnd(',');

    if (FreeCards.Contains(','))
    {
      int LastComma = FreeCards.LastIndexOf(',');
      FreeCards = FreeCards.Remove(LastComma, 1);
      FreeCards = FreeCards.Insert(LastComma, " og");
    }
    sqlReader.Close();
    sqlReader.Dispose();
    sqlCom.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
  }
  return FreeCards;
}
```

The controller function does not take any parameters, which is why I have left out the "data:" and "dataType:" parameters from the Ajax call.

When I call the function, the first Alert in the Success is triggered with the word "SUCCESS", but the second alert (where I want to display the returned value) displays "undefinded".

If I add the parameters "data: "{}"" to the Ajax call, the call fails and I get the alert('ERROR') shown, followed by the alert(request.responseText), and this alert actually contains the value I expect to get when the functions works.

Any suggestions how I can get the returned value when the Ajax call succeeds??

Comment: Your returning a string so what is `FreeCards = data.d;`? It should be just `FreeCards = data;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are returning a string this statement

```
FreeCards = data.d;
```

gives undefined only.. direct data will contain result. try chaning the line to

```
FreeCards = data
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Removing the "d" from data.d did the trick. Pretty much the only thing I hadn't tried :P Thanks!

Comment: I am glad that helped you :) But it would be nice if you follow the standards in calling the Ajax Request instead directly returning a String

Comment: I'm new to MVC and Ajax, so I'm still learning the "standards".

Answer (score 0):

You need to return json as:

```
public ActionResult FindFreeCards()
{
  string FreeCards = "";

  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gbizz"].ConnectionString))
  {
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlCom;
    SqlDataReader sqlReader;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gbizz"].ConnectionString);
    Con.Open();
    sqlCom = new SqlCommand("LicensePlateFindFreeCard", con);
    sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 12;

    sqlReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();

    if (sqlReader.HasRows)
    {
      while (sqlReader.Read())
      {
        FreeCards = FreeCards + sqlReader["CardNo"].ToString() + ", ";
      }
    }

    FreeCards = FreeCards.Trim().TrimEnd(',');

    if (FreeCards.Contains(','))
    {
      int LastComma = FreeCards.LastIndexOf(',');
      FreeCards = FreeCards.Remove(LastComma, 1);
      FreeCards = FreeCards.Insert(LastComma, " og");
    }
    sqlReader.Close();
    sqlReader.Dispose();
    sqlCom.Dispose();
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
  }
  return Json(new {d=FreeCards });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first on controller return as json using list to json as following:

```
        public ActionResult FindFreeCards()
        {
          List <string> FreeCards = new List<string>();

          using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gbizz"].ConnectionString))
          {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlCom;
            SqlDataReader sqlReader;
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gbizz"].ConnectionString);
            Con.Open();
            sqlCom = new SqlCommand("LicensePlateFindFreeCard", con);
            sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlCom.Parameters.Add("@CustomerId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 12;

            sqlReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();

            if (sqlReader.HasRows)
            {
              while (sqlReader.Read())
              {
                 FreeCards.add(sqlReader["CardNo"].ToString());
              }
            }


            sqlReader.Close();
            sqlReader.Dispose();
            sqlCom.Dispose();
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
          }
          return Json(FreeCards);
        }
```

Then parse ajax repsone using jQuery.parseJSON. Use following code :

```
               function FindFreeCards() 
    {
        $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("FindFreeCards", "AdminCards")',
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          type: 'POST',
          success: function (data) {
            /*New code */
            var data=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
             $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                                alert(i + " ==> "+  item );
                    });
            /*New code */
            alert('SUCCESS');

            var FreeCards;
            FreeCards = data.d;

            alert(FreeCards);

            $('#lblFreeCards').html(FreeCards);
            $('#modalSelectFreeCard').modal();
          },
          error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert('ERROR');
            alert(request.responseText);
            alert(status.toString());
            alert(error.toString());
          }
        });
    };
```